# Unable to identify which record is causing oracle exception Spring DATA JPA

Tags: oracle, spring-data-jpa

I have a method which is annotated with @Transactional and we are making a bulk update using save(Iterable  entities) method of SimpleJPARepository class of spring-data-jpa library. I have a scenario where i have nearly 20000 records are being processed by this method. There seems to be few entities which are not well formed in terms of datatypes as oracle column expects. For example : an attribute first name of entity has its value as "1234" ( which is not accepted by oracle DB as datatype in DB is VARCHAR ).

Because few records of 20000 records have this issue, save(Iterable entities) method throws "java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01722: invalid number" exception and doesnt save any of 20000 records. Is there a way i can identify which records are causing this exception and exclude them to update in the database?

I see there are couple of options like validation in  DOMAIN classes( which is not very feasible for me as i have lot of Domain classes and changing them is going to have a lot of impact for my application). One more option i see is using "JPA batch inserts with Hibernate". Again , even with this batch inserts approach i am not sure if i can get information on records which are causing the exception.

Any suggestions on this issue will be of great help.

Comment: have you tried using `save(S entity);` in a try block and log the objects which cause the exception in the catch block?

Comment: thanks for the reply . I didnot try using that method save(S entity); as number of records my application processes is very high. Generally my application processes 20k to 30k records. I felt it is not good in terms of performance to hit DB that number of times individually. Correct me if i am wrong

Comment: `saveAll` does the looping on the iterable internally, so it is the same performance wise or even worse because it returns a `List` of the saved elements, whereas doing `save (S entity)` you dont need to store the saved entities in a `List`. Look at the source code: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java#L536 If you care about performance you should look at batch operations.

Answer (score 0):

What you seemingly trying to do is let the database validate your data.

I consider this a bad idea in general but it doesn't really work with JPA.

Even though you stated that you don't want to fix your broken domain model, this is exactly what you should do:

- change the entities so that the types used do match those used in the database. Note that attempting to store a value of `"1234"` or `1234` in a `VARCHAR` or `VARCHAR2` column won't trigger the exception `ORA-01722: invalid number` because nothing is trying to convert anything to a number and even if it would, both values are a number or easily parsable into a number.
- add validation to ensure those constraints that can't be expressed by types (length of Strings for example).

The alternative would be a process like the following:

1. Persist a batch of entities.
2. If it succeeds commit. Done.
3. If it does not succeed split the batch into smaller batches and repeat from 1.

This is ugly and slow and might help to find all the constraints you need to check but it is not a good way to filter out those records that don't play nice with you database.